# Problem installing Maven plugin (m2eclipse) in Eclipse (Galileo)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven, m2eclipse

I have Eclipse Galileo (for Java EE Developers) installed, and I'm now trying to get the m2eclipse Maven plugin installed as well.

I follow the basic steps described at http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html, and it seems to be installing just fine. However, after restarting Eclipse after the install it doesn't seem to be anywhere. I should for instance have the ability to create a new maven project, but when the new-project wizard opens, there is no folder for Maven (I also cannot find any reference to it in the context menus of the existing projects I have).

When I click at Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details, I find "Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required)" in the tab "Installed Software", yet another thing pointing towards a successful installation (but I can't find it under the "Plug-ins" tab, should it be there too?)...

I feel like I'm just missing something *very* obvious, but right now I just don't see it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find the answer to this myself:

I had put the Eclipse installation folder under c:\Program Files\, but when I moved it directly under c:\ instead, the plug-in installation worked just as it should. I assume that is because Eclipse wasn't allowed to write to its own installation folder (but I didn't get the usual question from Windows that something was trying to access Program Files either...).

In one way I feel like I should be a bit ashamed that I didn't think of this before. On the other hand though, there could have been some reasonable error message stating that something failed during the plug-in installation...

Well, I hope this at least helps somebody else as well :)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, fixed the issue for me. I am rather surprised, as (in my case in Linux) additional plugins are stored in $HOME/.eclipse if you are missing write permissions on the installation folder, but this seems to not work correctly with m2eclipse.

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue and my eclipse installation is in c:\eclipse.

Comment: Are you perhaps running as a non-admin privileged user? I didn't have any more problem with this at all, so only thing I can come up with (or some other reason why your write-access to c: is limited?)...

Comment: No, I'm admin. I installed it into a new eclipse and that worked fine, but the old eclipse says it installs fine but then when I look under plugins there is nothing there. Just frustrating because I don't want to have to reconfigure an entire new eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the **[m2eclipse installation requirements](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Installation+Requirements)**?
In particular, you need WTP.

> "Maven integration for Eclipse" (core feature) and optional "Maven POM Editor" feature depend on the "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools" feature from WST
>   "Maven integration for WTP" feature provides Maven project configuration for WTP

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, as the following is stated just below in the requirements "You don't have to install WTP if you are using "Eclipse for Java" or "Eclipse for Java EE bundle and don't need "Maven WTP integration" feature" (and I have the Java EE bundle, and I don't need WTP integration).

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a previous version of m2eclipse installed? Did you uninstall it before to install the latest version? Just in case, does the following note applies to you?

> **Note about 0.9.8 Workspace Incompatibility:** If you are using
>   m2eclipse 0.10.0 with a workspace that
>   contains projects created under
>   m2eclipse 0.9.8, you must remove the
>   workspaceState.ser file. The
>   workspaceState.ser file is located
>   within the workspace directory in
>   $workspacedir/.metadata/.plugins/org.maven.ide.eclipse/workspaceState.ser.
>   If you remove this file, m2eclipse
>   0.10.0 will regenerate it as needed.

In my case, uninstalling the previous m2eclipse version didn't work and I had to start with a fresh Eclipse install (maybe try this also).

Regarding the plugin tab, this is what I have (to confirm that you should definitely find something):

[alt text http://www.imagebanana.com/img/84h6mw8z/screenshot_008.png](http://www.imagebanana.com/img/84h6mw8z/screenshot_008.png)

Note that I also installed some extras from m2eclipse Extras Update Site: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras

Comment: I have a clean install of Eclipse, so that shouldn't be the problem either. I just did an extra check on the plugin-tab as well, and I couldn't find anything from Sonatype, so there is for sure something missing :(

Comment: @Nailuj Fresh install and fresh workspace? Maybe check the *Error Log* to see if there is anything obvious.

Comment: Both workspace and the Eclipse install is fresh, yes (first time I install it on this computer). I've also looked through the log file (the .log found inside the .metadata folder in the workspace, right - or is there another one?), but I couldn't find anything out of the ordinary there either (Only some lines saying <"Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required)" will be ignored because it is already installed.> when I tried to force an update on the plugin)...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by going into Program Files, right click on the eclipse.exe file and select "Run as administrator". When I restarted Eclipse it said I had no plugins installs so I reinstalled and my problems were solved.

Comment: well, this follows naturally from my answer above. The reason why I wasn't able to install the Maven plugin was because the account I launched Eclipse from (my normal user account) didn't have write privileges to the *Program Files* folder (and it should not have such privileges there either...). And of course if you instead run Eclipse as administrator you will have these rights. However, running programs with administrative privileges should be avoided, so a better solution is to put Eclipse a place where your user *do* have sufficient rights.

Answer (score 0):

> PROBLEM SOLVED 
>   I had this same problem and I used the following software site:
>   ["M2Eclipse - http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.0] (without square brackets) to download the M2Eclipse plugin in Eclipse 3.7.0 (Indigo). For more information refer [this](http://harikrushnav.blogspot.com/2013/07/cannot-complete-install-because-one-or.html).

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of 'not getting Maven plugin running in eclipse' , it can be solved by altering admin rights to the .m2 folder . Right click on .m2 folder and go to network sharing. give all rights to all users. Restart eclipse and maven options will start to appear in Eclipse.