# Eclipse 3.5 Missing New Web Application option after installing Google App Engine plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, plugins

I just used Eclipse 3.5 to install the Google App Engine plug in. The plug in is showed as installed in the update manager. However, I am not seeing the option to "New Web Application Project" (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html). I also don't see anything Google related when I type Google into the search bar under Windows > Preferences.

There were no errors at the time of installation, and I was asked if I wanted to restart Eclipse, clicked yes, and it restarted accordingly. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any message in the Errors View?
Did you reproduce the issue with a fresh installation of Eclipse?

And where is installed your eclipse (what OS are you using)?
That can be relevant, because another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802849/problem-installing-maven-plugin-m2eclipse-in-eclipse-galileo) mentions:

> I had put the Eclipse installation folder under `c:\Program Files\`, but when I moved it directly under `c:\` instead, the plug-in installation worked just as it should.
>   I assume that is because Eclipse wasn't allowed to write to its own installation folder

Comment: Sweet, I'm at work now so I'll have to try that when I get home. Thanks!

Comment: @stevebot: fine! Although I would not recommend copying the Eclipse installation directory directly on `c:\`, rather in any user directory of yours (typically `c:\Users\YourName` for instance).

Answer (score 2):

solution: move the eclipse folder to X:\eclipse

I also downloaded eclipse 3.5 sp2 - Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, installed the GWT plugin, restarted eclipse as instructed and then
**File > New > Web Application Project** menu item does not exist in the eclipse.
it was in p:\eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32\eclipse

I moved te folder to p:\eclipse
uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin
now it works.

looks to me like a bug in the gwt plugin (win xp)

Answer (score 1):

Or easier:

Go to your eclipse folder > right click > uncheck to read only box.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're right about the problem having to do with permissions writing to the Program Files folder.

I'm on Windows 7 and had the same problem.  I also installed Eclipse under the Program Files folder, and got around this issue by running Eclipse "as administrator" when installing the Google plugins.  Worried that I would have similar problems installing other plugins, I moved my Eclipse installation to my C:\ directory and reinstalled the Google plugins without running as administrator.  That installation went just fine.

Someone else in [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4168) said he had that problem on one Windows 7 computer but not another.  My guess is that he installed Eclipse in the Program Files directory on his problem computer.